# Is any Finitely generated module over an Artinian ring , Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian, artinian

In order to prove a statement, I need to prove the following claim :

If $R $ is an (not necessarily commutative) Artinian ring and  $M $ is a finitely generated  $R $-module,  then $M$ is Noetherian.

I know that If $R $ is an Artinian ring and  $M $ is a finitely generated  $R $-module,  then $M$ is Artinian.

What about the claim?Is there any hint to prove that? Or any counterexample?

Thank you

Comment: Is your ring $R$ commutative?

Comment: @AlexWertheim no

Comment: Are you aware of the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem?

Comment: If the ring is Artinian then it is also Noetherian. Finitely generated modules over a Noetherian ring are Noetherian.

Comment: @AlexWertheim no

Comment: @Levent are you sure?Artinian ring is Noetherian?

Comment: @user115608 [the Hopkins Levitzki theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins–Levitzki_theorem). Alex already mentioned it. You should have looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Hopkins-Levitzki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem) theorem, it follows that an artinian ring is noetherian.

So you have that as your ring is artinian, then it is noetherian. And any finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is noetherian.